# Xcode Siri Intents: How to pass a variable from Intent Handler to IntentUI ViewController without including it in the response

Tags: swift, xcode, sirishortcuts

I need to pass a variable from the Intent Handler to the IntentViewController WITHOUT including it in the Response, so that it is displayed in the custom UI without Siri having to say it.

So far I have only been able to pass them using the Response like this:

```
completion(GetTimesIntentResponse.success(name: "SomeName", time: "5:40", location: LatestLocation.City))
```

However, this means Siri has to say this as part of the Response.  All I want is for `location` to be displayed in a label (in the Custom UI) without Siri having to read it out.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I didn't manage to find a way to do this directly, however the workaround is to save the variable(s) to Core Data in the Intent Handler and fetch them in the IntentViewController.  It is only a workaround, but effective in my case, as was only a single variable I needed to pass and was already storing it in Core Data elsewhere the App anyway.

Answer (score 4):

From `INUIHostedViewControlling` documentation:

> An Intents UI app extension works in tandem with a corresponding Intents app extension. The Intents app extension handles the intent and provides a response that includes data from your app. The view controller in your Intents UI app extension receives that data in the form of an INInteraction object and uses it to configure its view.

So, in your IntentHandler:

```
func handle(intent: GetTimesIntent, completion: @escaping (GetTimesIntentResponse) -> Void) {
    let activity = NSUserActivity(activityType: "com.your_company.your_identifier.get_times")
    activity.userInfo?["times_time"] = "5:40"
    activity.userInfo?["times_location"] = LatestLocation.City
    let response = GetTimesIntentResponse(code: .success, userActivity: activity)
    completion(response)
}
```

And in your IntentViewController:

```
func configureView(for parameters: Set<INParameter>, of interaction: INInteraction, interactiveBehavior: INUIInteractiveBehavior, context: INUIHostedViewContext, completion: @escaping (Bool, Set<INParameter>, CGSize) -> Void) {
    let data = interaction.intentResponse?.userActivity?.userInfo
    let time = data?["times_time"] as? String ?? "No time"
    let location = (data["times_location"] as? LatestLocation.City)?.name ?? "No city"
    label.text = "\(location) at \(time)"

    completion(true, parameters, self.desiredSize)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access your intent property, you can do this in the IntentViewController:

```
func configureView(for parameters: Set<INParameter>, of interaction: INInteraction, interactiveBehavior: INUIInteractiveBehavior, context: INUIHostedViewContext, completion: @escaping (Bool, Set<INParameter>, CGSize) -> Void) {

    let intent = interaction.intent as! YourIntent
    // let foo = intent.yourProperty // access your property from your intent
}
```

I hope this is what you meant.